# UL LI css menu issue

Tags: html, css

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cJCrj/4) which contains an `UL`:

```
<ul id="accordion2">
  <li>
    <div class="menuText">Product 1</div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="c-77-accessories.aspx">Accessories</a><ul>
          <li><a href="c-81-AAAC.aspx">AAAC</a></li>
          <li><a href="c-79-AAAC.aspx">AAAC</a></li>
          <li><a href="c-80-AAAC.aspx">AAAC</a></li>
          <li><a href="c-78-AAAC.aspx">AAAC</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="c-82-consumables.aspx">Consumables</a></li>
      <li><a href="c-76-products.aspx">Products</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="menuText">Product 2</div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="c-101-accessories.aspx">Accessories</a></li>
      <li><a href="c-102-consumables.aspx">Consumables</a></li>
      <li><a href="c-100-products.aspx">Products</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

...and my CSS:

```
ul#accordion2 li ul li {
display:none;
}

ul#accordion2 li:hover ul li {
display:block;
}
```

I want to hover on the div to show the options, then hovering on accessories should display the `li` options.

I cannot add a class to the `UL LI`, because it's created in an XML package.

It should fly out [like this](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/flyout2.html). How might I achieve this?

**EDIT: here are the gaps -** 
[image]

Comment: I'd suggest you start working on it, and come back if you run into trouble.

Comment: questions on SO work better if you have a specific question / problem. This kinda looks like `canihaztehcodez`.

Comment: ok, heres my update, new to css sorry. - http://jsfiddle.net/cJCrj/4/

Comment: I'm on it.... (I want the CSS rep)

Comment: down voting me? I even provided a working example in my comments?!!!

Comment: the problem is accessories doesnt want to show when on hover...

Comment: @PD24 Do you use a CSS reset style sheet?

Comment: No im not using a css reset. Which one would you suggest i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
#accordion2 li {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
}

#accordion2 ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 151px;
    top: 0;
}

#accordion2 li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/cJCrj/6/

Comment: you are really kind and considerate!

Comment: Sime, I am getting problems in IE7 with gaps appearing within the LI. any ideas on how to fix this? it works fine in FF

Comment: @PD24 I am surprised that it works in IE7... I don't have that browser, so I cannot test this. Make a screenshot of the issue and add it to your question via the "Image" button...

Comment: i have added the picture to the original post. The left is the start of the menu and i have taken a screenshot with it flying out.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/WvXWf/

Essentially you relatively position each `li`, then on hover show its child `ul` to the side using absolute positioning, and by toggling `display: none` to `display: block`.

And here's the relevant CSS:

```
#accordion2 li {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}
    #accordion2 li > ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 100px;
    }
    #accordion2 li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }
```

Here's a slightly prettier demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WvXWf/1/

Comment: Do you really indent your CSS like that or is it just some copy/pasting? Just curious.

Comment: I do, because I think it's easier to follow, since each child element is indented. Essentially the CSS matches the HTML.

Comment: Hmmm k. I already hate it when people use multi-line CSS rules :P Although just a style I know :)

Comment: It's definitely easier to read, particularly when you have a lot of properties in a single element. You can minimize the code before putting it in production, but at least in development I like optimizing readability. Particularly since I'm often not the only one working on a project.

Comment: @PeeHaa: CSS properties all on one line? That's usually quite hard to read (unless maybe you've already been staring at it for hours and have it memorized). How do you comment your code, especially specific properties? `str_replace(';', ";\n", $your_css)`

Comment: @Madmartigan reading CSS properties is what we have the browsers' dev tools for. :)

Comment: @Madmartigan I don't get it. Why would I wanna do something like that. If anything I would do `str_replace("\n", '', $mycss);`

Comment: @PeeHaa Do you not agree that it's easier to read the code at a glance when it's all on separate lines? Then you could just run a script like that to minimize it before putting it on your live site.

Comment: @PeeHaa: It was just a joke, I was telling to do that to your local css files :)

Comment: @Madmartigan can't believe I felt for that one :P